# How do I filter an array getting loaded from the api using another static array in javascript or typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I am trying to load the `sectionRoles` which only contains the one given in the array in `filterData` function but it doesn't return the filtered items.

How do I do this?

Simply, see the data contains a lot records but I want it to contain only the record which are given in the array.

```
  async getAllSectionRoles() {
        debugger;
        let data = await this.adminService.getAllSectionRoles().toPromise();
        this.sectionRoles = data;
        this.sectionRoles = data.filter(item => this.filterData(item.Id))
      }
    
      filterData(itemId) {
        let arr= [SectionRoleType.ResearchAndStudy,
                  SectionRoleType.Readings,
                  SectionRoleType.TaqareerAlBahasElmi,
                  SectionRoleType.TaqreerMoqaf,
                  SectionRoleType.WarqaSeyassie,
                  SectionRoleType.Derasat,
                  SectionRoleType.TaqareerDawreya,
                  SectionRoleType.ErhaabDowaly
                ];
    
        return arr.find(itemId);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of array , you can use Set here

Assuming your item.id is one of values from SectionRoleType

```
let arr= [SectionRoleType.ResearchAndStudy,
                  SectionRoleType.Readings,
                  SectionRoleType.TaqareerAlBahasElmi,
                  SectionRoleType.TaqreerMoqaf,
                  SectionRoleType.WarqaSeyassie,
                  SectionRoleType.Derasat,
                  SectionRoleType.TaqareerDawreya,
                  SectionRoleType.ErhaabDowaly
                ];
const filters = new Set(arr);
```

and then

```
this.sectionRoles = data.filter(item => filters.has(item.Id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.includes` for that

```
const arr= [SectionRoleType.ResearchAndStudy,
                  SectionRoleType.Readings,
                  SectionRoleType.TaqareerAlBahasElmi,
                  SectionRoleType.TaqreerMoqaf,
                  SectionRoleType.WarqaSeyassie,
                  SectionRoleType.Derasat,
                  SectionRoleType.TaqareerDawreya,
                  SectionRoleType.ErhaabDowaly
                ];
this.sectionRoles = data.filter(item => arr.includes(item.Id))
```